# How to add an icon image to the browser title bar?

Tags: html, css, favicon

I know this question is already asked many times, but for some reason I can't add my website's icon image inside the browser title bar, I've already tried this:

```
`<link rel="shortcut icon" type ="image/x-icon" href="location/image.ico">`
```

I put that code inside HTML `<head>`, below the `<title>` tag, but it still does not work. Did I make a silly mistake, or what? The image I used has the size of 16x16 pixel, and in `.ico` format.

Comment: That is the right way to load an icon.

Try flushing you'r cache.

In chrome it would be : F12, click and hold on the refresh and choose empty cache.

Comment: The favicon normally stays in the root directory `/favicon.ico` In fact you don't need to add that link at all - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 0):

If you use the html as provided in the question, it should work. Try to flush your cache.

Also visit this page to get cross-plattform support and optimized images.
[RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/)

On the page is also explained why you should not use an actual *.ico file.

> When your favicon is in the root directory, RealFaviconGenerator does not generate this code. This is because it somehow disrupts some other browsers like Chrome. And since IE looks for a file named favicon.ico anyway, the best solution is to not even talk about it.

[Resource](http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_ico_not_declared)

Answer (score 0):

Read this article and you may know how to deal it[rel="shortcut icon" considered harmful](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon),

If you want your favicon to load you can simply use this code:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally you had to name your site icon file , `favicon.ico` and you were required to upload it to the root of your site.

Example - `Site: http://www.domain.com
            Root: http://www.domain.com/
            Icon: http://www.domain.com/favicon.ico`

Now the requirements are less strict and what you have is correct (as long as you remembered to upload the icon to your site)

Current - `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="location/image.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Try the older way and see if you get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Try to use the reload button. It will flush the catch and load the page again, chances are there it should display the new favicon!